# Unable to post HTTP request from angular to node js localhost server

Tags: node.js, angular, post

I have an express node js server, which listens to localhost at port 3000, and prints the JSON content.
If I use postman, it prints the JSON properly.

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json())

var port = 3000;

app.post('/instance', function(req, res) {
    const obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body))
    console.log(obj);
    //res.send(req.body);
});


// start the server
app.listen(port);
console.log('Server started! At http://localhost:' + port);
```

In angular html, i have an ngFor that sends a list item when a button is clicked.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let instance of instancesList">
    <tr class="col-sm border border-primary" style="color:#111111">
      <td>{{instance.id}}</td>
      <td>{{instance.name}}</td>
      <td>{{instance.zone}}</td>
      <td>{{instance.ip}}</td>
      <td> <button (click)="onClick(instance)" type="button" class="btn border-primary btn-lg">test</button></td>
    </ng-container>
```

At this point, when the button is clicked, I want a JSON with the item data to be sent to the server, and just be printed. It does not happen, the server doesn't print the json content, but it prints the content if sent from postman.

i've been strugling for a few days now, I appreciate any help.

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
  })
};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

@Injectable({providedIn:'root'})
export class AppComponent{
  instancesList = instances;
  baseUrl = "http://localhost:3000/instance"

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { } 

  onClick(instance: Instance) : Observable<Instance>{
    const json = JSON.stringify(instance)

    return this.http.post<Instance>(this.baseUrl, json, httpOptions)

    // prints the json on the webpage just for testing
    alert(JSON.stringify(instance));       
}
}
```

I tried searching stackoverflow and try different methods, none helped.

Answer (score 0):

you didn't `subscribe` to the `Observable` returned from the the HTTP request.
simply instead of return it - do that:

```
this.http.post<Instance>(this.baseUrl, json, httpOptions).subscribe(data => 
 { 
   // here you can do something with the data that returned
 })
```

Comment: I already tried that, it still does not work.

onClick(instance: Instance){
    const json = JSON.stringify(instance)

    this.http.post<Instance>(this.baseUrl, json, httpOptions).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data)
    })

     
    //alert(JSON.stringify(instance));       
}

Comment: it's not something that you "trying" - you need to `subscribe` for it, otherwise nothing will happened.

Comment: also remove the `alert` from there - it's blocking the app

Comment: I edited it to subscribe instead of returning it. but it still does not work. could there be any more issues with the http post?
Does anything has to be inside the http constructor?
תודה מראש

Comment: try to see of you get any errors: `this.http.post<Instance>(this.baseUrl, json, httpOptions).subscribe(data => 
 { 
   // here you can do something with the data that returned
 }, error => console.log(error))`

Comment: open the console in the browser, see if you get any errors there

Answer (score 0):

So just in case, somebody finds this in the future, the issue was related to something else

> CORS error due to browser's same origin policy.
> To get around this, you need to tell your browser to enable your
> client and your server to share resources while being of different
> origins. In other words, you need to enable cross-origin resource
> sharing or CORS in your application.

The solution is to add a proxy config as stated in the official angular documentation.
https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server